What is the Fourier series of periodic $|t|$?

Find the Fourier series of the function $f(t)$ with period $2π$ given by $f(t) = |t|$ on $(−π, π)$.

I get $$f(t) = \frac \pi 2 - \frac 4 \pi \sum_{\text{n odd}}\frac {\cos nt}{n^2}$$
but MIT OCW claims its

Who's correct?

there is a typo in the notes - they correctly write the series but forget the $1/2$ at the end - an easy check shows that your version is correct though the notes also finds it, just having a typo at the end

Yes, we know or can deduce $\sum_{n\ odd} \frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}8,$ and your sum gives $f(0)=0.$
